# Definite integral of exponential of trig function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am trying to do the following integral:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-A(b+c\cos\phi)^2} d\phi$$

where $A>0$, $b>0$, and $c$ real. I have tried trig substitutions, differentiating under the integral, Fourier transforming, without any luck. I know I can replace $\cos$ with $\sin$ without changing the value of the integral, because it is over the full period. I also know that in the case that $b=0$ the answer is simply a Bessel function, but indeed the presence of both $\cos$ and $\cos^2$ in the exponential is what makes it tricky.  Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Numerical integration may be the best way forward in this case.

Comment: Solution only with fast converging  series: $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 \left(-A b^2\right)^k \pi  \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}+k;1;-A c^2\right)}{\Gamma (1+k)}=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{2 (-1)^j A^j c^{2 j} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}
   (1+2 j)\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}+j;\frac{1}{2};-A b^2\right)}{\Gamma (1+j)^2}$$

Comment: Wow this is perfect for my purposes! Thank you! Can I ask for a couple hints on how you got this?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Nick has a question for you about your comment. I think the second series is for the integral  $$2 \int_{\cos (0)}^{\cos (\pi )} -\frac{e^{-A^2 (b-c y)^2}}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy,$$ but I'm not sure about first series. I think your comment is worth expanding on and raising to an answer, as I don't think Nick is going to get a better answer than yours (assuming a little explanation is added).